# display background image that needs to repeat but does not have a repeating pattern

Tags: html, css

I have a background that does not have an obvious repeating pattern and I need help adding this to my webpage as a background.

The attached image is the main page background. After the web browser hits 1280+ px, the main background stays in the center and the right and left sides fade out to white as seen in the attached image.

I don't know how I can smooth the transition of the background once the page height is larger than the height of the background image height, there is no repeating pattern and I don't know of a good way to make it a smooth/seamless transition once the page height reaches that point.

[image]

Comment: If you want to repeat the pattern you need a repeating pattern. Find somebody who knows how to use photoshop. It would be fairly simple with your image

Comment: @3rror404 are you saying this is not possible unless it is a repeating pattern?

Comment: It is of course possible to use CSS to make it repeat, but it will simply tile the image a la Windows Desktop background "tile" option. If you want a smooth transition that fades out to white on the edges, then you might need to edit the image in Photoshop.

Comment: Without a image that may seemlessly repeat (in y-direction in this case) you cannot have a repeating background-image.

Comment: you can also play around with border-image: http://jsfiddle.net/NicoO/2a99n/1/

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting mind exercise. I'm sure there are many ways to accomplish this, but the way I would likely achieve it offhand is with an extra div that has an opacity gradient and a media query.

Create a div before the closing `</body>` tag, and give it whatever height you want the 'fade-out' to be.

`<div id="fadeout"></div>`

And in your stylesheet:

```
body {
    background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/70dUX.jpg') top center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin: 0;
}
#fadeout {
    display: none;
}

@media all and (min-height: 529px) {
    #fadeout {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 439px;
        background: #333;
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,0), rgba(255,255,255,1));
    }
}
```

This should give the appearance of a fadeout to the white background. Obviously configure the heights to the correct background height, I just used 529px because that's how big the image you listed above is.

JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/prex/kAwce/

[image]